# AutoIncrement based on Field Value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, python-parser, autoincrement

Is there any way to automatically restart the AutoIncrement () function based on the Field Value on ArcMap?

I am developing a model in  ModelBuilder to name parcels automatically. The polygons are already sorted on the order they should be. I need to execute the AutoIncrement function on each of the Field Values separately.
To simplify the problem, the result I need is shown below. I already have the !Name! field and based on that, the !Count! field result must be acquired automatically.

[image: Example Count]

Comment: Thanks...Possibly a duplicate question, however I coudn't quite understand the answer. How should I apply the field calculation with that solution?

Comment: Seek "advanced field calculations" in help.